# Laravel customer API resource with relationships

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

> Controller function:

```
public function index () {
    // TESTED
    // The getAllActiveSuppliers() function just return Supplier::pagniate(10)
    $suppliers = $this -> model -> getAllActiveSuppliers();
    return new SupplierResource($suppliers);
}
```

> Returned Json:

```
    {
    "current_page": 1,
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 23,
            "name": "Test Name",
            "description": "Test Description",
            "created_by": {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "Test 1",
                "email": "admin@admin.com",
                "email_verified_at": null,
                "active": 1,
                "created_at": "2018-10-12 14:17:38",
                "updated_at": "2018-10-12 14:17:38"
            },
            "updated_by": {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "Test 1",
                "email": "admin@admin.com",
                "email_verified_at": null,
                "active": 1,
                "created_at": "2018-10-12 14:17:38",
                "updated_at": "2018-10-12 14:17:38"
            },
            "deleted_at": null,
            "created_at": "2018-10-31 01:46:11",
            "updated_at": "2018-11-02 22:05:14",

        }
    ],
    ...
}
```

> What I am trying to do:

In the **created_by and updated_by** I just want to show `name, email` nothing else.

> What I have tried to do:

I have tried to create an API resource collection

**Supplier.php API Resource Collection :**

```
public function toArray($request)
{
    return parent::toArray($request);
}
```

Comment: Do you mean `created_by` and `updated_by`?

Comment: @TravisBritz yes, sorry typo

Answer (score 3):

For anyone that may still need this as I was searching for myself in this topic

First create a resource for your relation with name, email fields

```
class UserResource extends JsonResource
{

    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            'name' => $this->name,
            'email' => $this->email,
        ];
    }
}
```

Then create SupplierResource with relation created_by to User

```
class SupplierResource extends JsonResource
{

    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            'id' => $this->id,
            'name' => $this->name,
            'description' => $this->description,
            'created_by' => new UserResource($this->created_by)
        ];
    }
}
```

In the Controller

```
public function index () {

    $suppliers = $this->model->getAllActiveSuppliers();
    
    return SupplierResource::collection($suppliers);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You first need to define a structure for a *singular* JsonResource object:

```
public function toArray($request)
{
    return [
        'id' => $this->id,
        'name' => $this->name,
        ...
        'created_by' => $this->created_by->only('name', 'email'),
        ...
    ];
}
```

And then tell your ResourceCollection to use the class:

> #### Customizing The Underlying Resource Class
>
> Typically, the
>   `$this->collection` property of a resource collection is automatically
>   populated with the result of mapping each item of the collection to
>   its singular resource class. The singular resource class is assumed to
>   be the collection's class name without the trailing `Collection`
>   string.
>
> For example, `UserCollection` will attempt to map the given user
>   instances into the `User` resource. To customize this behavior, you may
>   override the `$collects` property of your resource collection

(From https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-resources#concept-overview)

If your ResourceCollection doesn't do anything extra, you might not need it. Every JsonResource can transform itself for a collection with the `collection()` method, e.g. `JsonResource::collection($models)`

Comment: The problem is that I am returning a collection.. Please take a look at my question edit

Comment: @Ahmedessam I have edited my answer to apply to resource collections rather than single json resources

Answer (score 0):

Think we can add item to `parent::toArray($request)`

```
public function toArray($request)
    {
        $array = parent::toArray($request);
        $array['created_by'] = $this->created_by->only('name', 'email');
        return $array;
    }
```